# "Merge" two identical branches

Tags: git, git-merge

In my repo I had a master branch and a bugfix branch. I did my bugfix, and merged it into master. Then, in a fit of madness over a silly mistake I did the unthinkable. I added 3 characters to master after the merge with `git commit --amend`. I rewrote history. Then, to my dismay, it only affected master, and not bugfix, so that if I run (on master) `git branch --no-merged` I see that bugfix isn't merged. So, I checkout bugfix and make the same changes such that `git diff bugfix master` returns nothing, and then from master I check `git branch --no-merged` again, and it still says bugfix isn't merged. So, now I have 2 identical branches which I would like to be merged that aren't, and I don't want to use another commit. How can I combine them so git sees them as merged and `git branch --no-merged` doesn't return bugfix?

Comment: Undo the merge commit, merge again, and go from there.  I don't think the path you are on is going to bear any fruit (at least none you would want to eat).

Comment: Even after you do the amend, the commit still has the two parents and is a merge commit, so doesn't make sense that after that bugfix shows up in --no-merged.

Comment: @DavidN I don't know why it happened, I'm just listing what happened to me. I'll try and reproduce it and let you know if I can.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen If you write that up as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes when you are lost on a trail, the most prudent thing to do is to retrace your steps to a previous point when you were not lost.  In your case, I would undo the amended merge commit in `master` and also nuke the "fix" commit in `bugfix`.  Then redo the merge without any additional changes.

**Undo bad commit in bugfix:**

```
git checkout bugfix       # switch to bugfix
git reset --hard HEAD~1   # nuke the fix commit
```

**Undo merge commit in master:**

```
git checkout master       # switch to master
git reset --hard HEAD~1   # nuke the amended merge commit
```

Now you can redo the merge:

```
git merge bugfix
```

Note: This answer assumes that you have not already pushed anything to the remote.  If you have, then you'll want to use `git revert` to undo the bad commits instead of rewriting history.